# .NET Core API stalls on high load

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-8.5

I'm currently in the first phase of optimizing a gaming back-end. I'm using .NET Core 2.0, EF and MySQL. Currently all of this is running on a local machine, used for dev. To do initial load testing, I've written a small console app that simulates the way the final client will use the API. The API is hosted under IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012R2 machine. The simulating app is run on 1-2 separate machines.

So, this all works very well for around 100-120 requests/s. The CPU load is around 15-30 on the server, the number of connections on the MySQL server averaging around 100 (I've set the max_connections to 400, and it's never near that value). Response times are averaging way below 100ms. However, as soon as we enter request figures a bit higher than that, it seems the system completely stalls on intervals. The CPU load **drops** to < 5, and the response times in the same time skyrockets. So, it kind of acts like a traffic jam situation. During the stall, both the MySQL and the dotnet exe's seem to "rest".

I do realize I'm no where near a production setup on anything, the MySQL instance is in dev etc. However, I'm still curious what would be the cause of this. Any ideas?

Comment: This eventually sounds as if you are running into deadlock storm when having reached a certain load. Did you debug the locks?

Comment: @binarus, tbh I dont know how I would go about doing that really. any hints?

Comment: Provided that you use InnoDB, look into `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. You might also read more in-depth articles like [that one](http://abiasforaction.net/debugging-transactional-and-locking-issues-in-mysql/).

Comment: @Binarus so, I ran the command at one of the stalls, and got the following output: https://pastebin.com/VibFxrKy anything in there that seems odd to you?

Comment: I am experiencing kind of the same behavior, but on Linux app service in Azure, .NET Core 3.1, Azure SQL Server, ... But same symptoms. All is fine to a certain load, when it exceeds that limit, all just freezes and waits for like 20-40 s and then it is superfast again. Any news regarding this?